# IBM Bluemix IotFoundation : Iotfclient is offline. Retrying connection

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, iot

I am trying to follow the IBM Bluemix course on Coursera.

1. My steup: A raspberry pi as a device (client) which is connected as a registered client to Watson IoT Platform. It's emitting a continuous stream of random  numbers per second.
2. I have deployed my custom Nodejs app (code that is available on Coursera) on IBM Bluemix.

   ```
   var express = require('express');

   var app = express();
   var Client = require('ibmiotf');
   var appConfig;

   var serverPort = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;
   var serverHost = process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost';

   if (process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
       var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
   appConfig = {
                  'org' : env["iotf-service"][0].credentials.org,
                  'id' : 'dna-nodeserver',
                  'auth-key' : env["iotf-service"][0].credentials.apiKey,
                  'auth-token' : env["iotf-service"][0].credentials.apiToken
                 }
   } else {
       appConfig = require('./application.json');
   }

   var responseString = 'Hello Coursera';

   var appClient = new Client.IotfApplication(appConfig);

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       res.send(responseString);
   });
   var server = app.listen(serverPort, serverHost, function() {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log('Listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

   appClient.connect();

   appClient.on('connect', function() {
       appClient.subscribeToDeviceEvents('raspberrypi');
   });

   appClient.on("error", function (err) {
       console.log("Error : "+err);
   });

   appClient.on('deviceEvent', function(deviceType, deviceId, eventType, format, payload) {

       responseString = "Device Event from :: "+deviceType+" : "+deviceId+" of event "+eventType+" with payload : "+payload;

       console.log("Device Event from :: "+deviceType+" : "+deviceId+" of event "+eventType+" with payload : "+payload);
   });

   });
   ```

The problem that I am facing is shown is the screenshot below:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTnjZ.png)

Also, since I am receiving continuous events from the raspberry pi... the webpage (served by res.send(responseString)) should show the changes automatically ...without the need for me to manually refresh the page. But this does **not** seem to happen.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple applications listening to events. Stop the previous Node Red Application on Bluemix. Instead only run the Nodejs app shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but thanks to Alexei for pointing me in the right direction.

In my case the same behaviour testing a local version of an event broker when the production version is still running in IBM Cloud.

You *can* have multiple listeners in this way if you generate an additional API key, save both sets of credentials, and check a suitable environment variable to see which set to apply.

In my app, I wrap these in a function in node:

```
function getEventBrokerCredentials(siteCode) {

    var codeToCredentials = {
        'REMOTE_BROKER': {
            'orgId': 'abcde',
            'id': 'ThisIsABroker',
            'apikey': '111111111111111',
            'authtoken': '2222222222222'
        },
        'LOCAL_BROKER': {
            'orgId': 'abcde',
            'id': 'ThisIsALocalBroker',
            'apikey': '3333333333333333',
            'authtoken': '4444444444444'
        }
    };

    return codeToCredentials[siteCode];
}


var brokerCredentials = getEventBrokerCredentials(process.env.BROKER_HOST || 'REMOTE_BROKER');


var appClient = new IOTClient.IotfApplication({
    'org': brokerCredentials.orgId,
    'id': brokerCredentials.id,
    'auth-key': brokerCredentials.apikey,
    'auth-token': brokerCredentials.authtoken
});
```

and then use

```
BROKER_HOST=LOCAL_BROKER nodemon
```

for local testing and development.

There are many variations on this theme of course.